# Как удалить столбцы или строки , в которых по меньшей мере X значений НЕ Nan?

Tags: python, pandas

С помощью dropna я могу удалить столбцы или строки в которых сколько-то значений Null?
Например:

```
#Датафрейм gl3: удалить из gl1 сначала строки, в которых по меньшей мере 130 значений Nan, 
gl3 = gl1.dropna(thresh=130, axis=0)
#а потом столбцы, в которых по меньшей мере 140100 значений Nan.
gl3 = gl3.dropna(thresh=140100, axis=1)
```

А как удалить столбцы или строки, в которых по меньшей мере сколько-то значений НЕ Nan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

самый простой вариант - воспользоваться методом `count` (он считает значения, игнорируя NaN), как-то так:

```
# для колонок:
df[df.columns[(df.count()>140100)]]

#для строк:
df.loc[(df.count(axis=1)>130)]
```